# filtering while downloading a dataset R

Tags: r, download, dataset, subset

There is a large dataset that I need to download over the web using R, but I would like to learn how to filter it at the same time while downloading to the Dates that I need.  Right now, I have it setup to download and .unzip and then I create another data set with a filter.  The file is a text ";" delimited file

There is a Date column with format 1/1/2009 and I need to only select two dates, 3/1/2009 and 3/2/2009, how to do that in R ?

When I import it, R set it as a factor, since I only need those two dates and there is no need to do a Between, I just select the two factors and call it a day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can filter while downloading. To select only these dates you can use the `subset` function:

```
# do not convert string to factors
d.all = read.csv(file, ..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ';')
# Date column is called DATE:
d.filter = subset(d.all, DATE %in% c("1/1/2009", "3/1/2009"))
```

Comment: Ahhh ok, wasn't sure, that's why I asked, thanks!  I already have it working the best I can then, thank again!